# Не работает функция file_get_contents

Tags: php

На docs.google.com у меня лежит документ, который я должен загрузить в csv формате. С этим все отлично, при переходе по ссылке файл скачивается с нужным форматом.
Но когда я использую такой код:

```
<?php
   $filename = "https://docs.google.com/...;
   echo file_get_contents($filename);
?>
```

Сервер выдает ошибку:
`Warning: file_get_contents(https://docs.google.com/...): failed to open stream *куча квадратов в восклицательными знаками* in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 4`

Если перед ссылкой добавить функцию urlencode(), появляется читаемая ошибка:

`Warning: file_get_contents(https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 4`

Причем функция не работает с любыми ссылками, даже например https://google.com. Везде выдает одно и то же. Проверял локально и на хостинге. 
Версия php 7.1.10. Права ко всей папке поставил 777.

Цель задания является просто скачивание и сохранение файла на сервере. (с помощью file_put_contents). Примечательно, что все работало на старом хостинге.

`var_dump(file_get_contents($filename));` выводит bool(false) при любых ссылках.

`allow_url_fopen` стоит значение on

Comment: Как-то мало информации. Что за три точки в конце `$filename`, да ещё и не закрытых кавычками? У меня при указании пути к конкретному документу открывает авторизацию гугл

Comment: Я просто не стал прописывать полный путь. При переходе по той ссылке он все прекрасно скачивает.

Comment: `Если вы открываете URI, содержащий спецсимволы, такие как пробел, вам нужно закодировать URI при помощи urlencode().` - это из оф доки. Проверьте на простом файле, если не сработает, обращайтесь в саппорт хостинга.

Comment: Проблема то в том, что пробелов у меня нету и локально с апачем тоже оказывается работать. В ссылке присутствуют символы :,/,?,=,&,-. Как я понимаю, все должно работать. И повторю, не работают вообще любые ссылки.

Comment: Странно, `https://google.com` у меня открывает... php 7.1 и апач из пакета OpenServer

Comment: Попробуйте для начала не https.

Comment: вы файл скачиваете, потому что авторизированы в гугле, попробуйте выйти из аккаунта и перейти по той ссылке, что в итоге?

Comment: Все проверено - работает, потому что использовал функцию "Опубликовать в интернете". Такой способ не требует авторизацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно в настройках отключена опция `allow_url_fopen`, которая позволяет работать с удаленными файлами.

Либо попробуйте аналог на CURL:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: С помощью этой функции ошибки не появляются, но ничего и не выводится. 

    $filename =  "https://google.com";
    echo file_get_contents_curl($filename);